# Redirect Loop Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I've been beating my head against the wall on this one - I have code that I use to test if a user is trying to access an account they're associated with and if not redirects them to their own account. Basically it's to stop people from accessing via URL routes accounts other than theirs.

This code works without issue on other sites I've built but for some reason it's not working on a new project.

The code in question:

```
def set_company
  if params[:id].nil?
    @company = Company.find(current_contact.company_id)
  else
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    if @company.id != current_contact.company_id
        redirect_to(company_path(current_contact.company_id), alert: 'You can\'t access that account This is not your account!!! This one is.' )
    end
  end
end
```

In theory when the if statement returns true, it should redirect to the company_path with the params ID set from the current user. On the second run of this code it should find the company based on the params id and then return false when checking if the company ID doesn't match the current user's company id, but instead I get a "this page has a redirect loop" error.

Comment: Making a CRM system are we? Looks good :)

Comment: Something like that - more an shared workspace management system, but very similar

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hitting the `db` with the `find` method - I think you'll be better validating against pure values, and only then performing the `find` method:

```
def set_company
  if params[:id].nil?
    @company = Company.find(current_contact.company_id)
  else
    redirect_to(company_path(current_contact.company_id), alert: 'You can\'t access that account This is not your account!!! This one is.' ) if params[:id] != current_contact.company_id
    @company = Company.find params[:id]
  end
end
```

Comment: It's a good idea on skipping the call to the DB, but what I'm trying to stop is a user who types in a URL that would be associated with a different company and one they shouldn't have access to. In your sample code this test is missing. I'm guessing the problem is actually caused by the fact that the redirect is to the show method and the test is on the show page. Found some stuff online that hints at that.

Answer (score 0):

try this..using `present`

```
def set_company
  if params[:id].present?
    @company = Company.find(current_contact.company_id)
  else
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    if @company.id != current_contact.company_id
        redirect_to(company_path(current_contact.company_id), alert: 'You can\'t access that account This is not your account!!! This one is.' )
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure I follow your suggested structure. Shouldn't it be structured this way: `if params[:id].present?
        @company = Company.find(params[:id])
        if @company.id != current_contact.company_id
          redirect_to(company_path(current_contact.company_id), alert: 'You can\'t access that account This is not your account!!! This one is.' )
        end`
      else
        @company = Company.find(current_contact.company_id)
      end